# Need help making this page responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I've been trying for 3 days to make my contact form line up with an iframe map embedded in the same page.There are 4 main divs. (1) iframe header (2) iframe position (3) form header (4) form position:

```
<div class="iframeTitle">How to Find Us</div>
<div class="iframepos">
<div class="contactTitle">Contact Us</div>
<div class="form_pos">
```

I've added Media Queries to the code, but still have issues even when using online tools that show how the site appears in different resolutions.

If you expand/contract the width bar in the dem found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/enz619jy/1/) you can see how the map and form aren't always side-by-side. The demo includes most of my code, because I felt it's all relevant since this issue deals with responsive design.

Any feedback or fixes would be so amazing. Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about. The person below posted an answer and now my problem is solved. 1 question, 1 answer. Seems pretty efficient to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a page responsive, you really need to wrap your elements in divs. Your current structure is:

```
<header>

    <div class="iframeTitle"></div>
    <div class="iframepos"></div>

</header>
<div class="contactTitle"></div>

<div class="form_pos"></div>

<div class="OfficeEmail"></div>

<div class="OfficeToll"></div>

<div class="OfficeLocal"></div>

<div class="OfficeFax"></div>

<div class="DropBy"></div>

<div class="Address1"></div>

<div class="Address2"></div>
```

It should be something like this:

```
<header>

        <div class="iframeTitle"></div>
        <div class="iframepos"></div>

</header>

<div id="CONTACT_FORM">
    <div class="contactTitle"></div>

    <div class="form_pos"></div>
</div>
<div id="ADDRESS">

    <div class="OfficeEmail"></div>

    <div class="OfficeToll"></div>

    <div class="OfficeLocal"></div>

    <div class="OfficeFax"></div>

    <div class="DropBy"></div>

    <div class="Address1"></div>

    <div class="Address2"></div>
</div>
```

And then apply styles with media query to the wrap elements.

This should be your starting point.